# Create N tables from a base table with table names derived from column values without a for loop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have one big origin table which I want to split in several smaller tables based on the category.

| id | Category | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | yellow |
| 2 | plane | blue |
| 3 | plane | green |
| 4 | car | blue |
| 5 | bus | blue |
| 5 | plane | yellow |

```
Table name: car
| id | Category | color |
| ---| -------- | ----- |
| 1  | car      | yellow|
| 4  | car      | blue  |
```

Table name: plane

| id | Category | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | plane | blue |
| 3 | plane | green |
| 5 | plane | yellow |

Table name: bus

| id | Category | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | bus | blue |

This is one potential solution:

```
df_tmp = df_transportation.groupBy("category").count()
categories = list(df_tmp["category"])
for category in categories:
   df_cat = df_transportation.filter(col("category") == "category))
   df_cat.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable(f'{category}'
```

Is there a way to get to the same solution without a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done with a one liner.

```
# create df
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
    [1, 'A', 20220722, 1],
    [1, 'A', 20220723, 1],
    [1, 'B', 1, 0],
    [2, 'B', 20220722, 1],
    [2, 'C', 0, 0],
    [2, 'B', 20220724, 3],
]),
                           ['ID', 'State', 'Time', 'Expected'])

+---+-----+--------+--------+
| ID|State|    Time|Expected|
+---+-----+--------+--------+
|  1|    A|20220722|       1|
|  1|    A|20220723|       1|
|  1|    B|       1|       0|
|  2|    B|20220722|       1|
|  2|    C|       0|       0|
|  2|    B|20220724|       3|
+---+-----+--------+--------+
```

Solution

```
l  = dict(zip(v:=sorted(set(df.select('State').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())),[df.where(col('State')==x) for x in v] ))

l.get('B').show()

+---+-----+--------+--------+
| ID|State|    Time|Expected|
+---+-----+--------+--------+
|  1|    B|       1|       0|
|  2|    B|20220722|       1|
|  2|    B|20220724|       3|
+---+-----+--------+--------+
```

How it works

I create a dictionary of element and its filter in the dataframe.

Using; `v:=sorted(set(df.select('State').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()))` Using the walrus operator I store the unique elements in the column `State` in a variable `v`

using; `[df.where(col('State')==x) for x in v]` I store filtered dataframe of each element in the main df

Using `dict(zip())` I store the two outcomes above in a dictionary.

using `l.get('B').show()` I call a dataframe in the dict whose key is `B`

Comment: I need to write the DF to a table and the table name needs to contain the value in the column "category". Can you do that without a for loop?

Comment: You must loop through the column using either a for loop or list comprehension. Whats the problem storing as follwos `df_B=l.get('B')`

Comment: Looping through a column using a for loop slows down the spark execution.

Comment: We are not looping. The unique elements in the column are saved in a list/set. You loop the list using elements to filter. Please note the difference